# If first name exists, it shows data

Tags: php, input, exists

I am trying to make it so it would check if the user has a firstname, if not then it will create a empty placeholder for them to enter it, but if they do have a first name it will display the first name in the box.
There are no errors coming up, if is just not working, please help me.

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" <?php if(isset($_user_data["first_name"])) // Checks if exists { ?> value="<?php echo $user_data['first_name']; // Echos if exists ?>" <?php } else // Or shows empty placeholder { ?> placeholder="First name" <?php } ?> style="width: 200px;">
```

Thanks

Comment: You're *probably* getting syntax errors from attempting to use comments like that with all of your code on *one line*.  At the very least, it's going to confuse the parser in some way.  Try using some carriage returns from time to time.  It not only makes the syntax cleaner, it also makes the code human-readable.  Which is important when you, as a human, want to debug it.

Comment: I'm not getting any syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you check it it's set, not if the variable contains any data... add

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" <?php if(isset($user_data["first_name"]) && $user_data["first_name"] != '') // Checks if exists { ?> value="<?php echo $user_data['first_name']; // Echos if exists ?>" <?php } else // Or shows empty placeholder { ?> placeholder="First name" <?php } ?> style="width: 200px;">
```

Comment: yes its valid "Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*' "

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using wrong variable name:

```
$_user_data["first_name"]
```

Should be:

```
$user_data["first_name"]
```

**Side note:**

`$_user_data` also a valid variable name for using as variable.

Comment: `$_` is completely valid in php

Comment: @dagon valid but invalid for OP

Comment: @dagon issue is not defining a variable issue is calling or using a variable

Comment: @dagon I hopecu will consider your down voting. :)

Answer (score 0):

I removed the current structure where you try to do everything inside the one input. I find this more structured but I guess thats personal preference

```
<?php if(isset($user_data["first_name"])){ ?>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<?php echo $user_data['first_name']; ?>"/>
<?php } else { ?>
 <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name"/>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This would mean that if the variable isn't set the input would show "placeholder" instead of "First Name"

Comment: @meame69 Oops my bad. Changed it!